Define make rule to modify make variable
I'm trying to define a make rule that modifies a make variable, as a way to conditionally compile the code.
Something like:
[...]
LD_PREL:=

all: main

main: $(OBJ)
    $(COMP) $(DEBUG) $(FLAGS) $^ -shared -o libname.so $(LIBS)

main_ld: ld_prel_def $(OBJ)
    $(COMP) $(DEBUG) $(FLAGS) $^ -shared -o libname_ld.so $(LIBS)

ld_prel_def:
    $(eval LD_PREL:=-DWITH_LD_PRELOAD)
    echo $(LD_PREL)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: src/%.c $(DEPS)
    $(COMP) $(DEBUG) $(FLAGS) $(DDEFS) $(TDEFS) $(LD_PREL) $(WARN) -c -fPIC -o $@ $<


From the echo line, it seems that it is working as expected:
echo -DWITH_LD_PRELOAD
-DWITH_LD_PRELOAD

except that the linker than throws error:
/usr/local/bin/ld: cannot find ld_prel_def: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:27: main_ld] Error 1

What am I doing wrong?

Well, did you look at the compile lines make prints?  Forget whether you see the echo command: do you see the extra option being provided when make invokes the compiler?

Oh, I see the problem.  This rule:
main_ld: ld_prel_def $(OBJ)
         $(COMP) $(DEBUG) $(FLAGS) $^ -shared -o libname_ld.so $(LIBS)

uses $^ which resolves to all the prerequisites.  One of the prerequisites is your target ld_prel_def which obviously is not a valid object file, so your linker fails.
You could use:
main_ld: ld_prel_def $(OBJ)
         $(COMP) $(DEBUG) $(FLAGS) $(filter %.o,$^) -shared -o libname_ld.so $(LIBS)

In general, as with almost any use of $(eval ...) inside recipes, this is a pretty brittle way to write a makefile IMO.  What if some of the objects are compiled one way, say without the option, and then you run make main_ld and compile the rest of the objects that aren't up to date the other way?  Now you have a mix of some objects built one way and some built the other way.

I see. Thanks for the fix.
Re: "In general, as with almost any use of $(eval ...) inside recipes, this is a pretty brittle way to write a makefile IMO." Can you elaborate more? How would you do in such case?

Re: "What if some of the objects are compiled one way, say without the option, and then you run make main_ld and compile the rest of the objects that aren't up to date the other way? Now you have a mix of some objects built one way and some built the other way.".
I did it this way exactly because I know that all of the object files must follow the same conditions. In fact, that conditional definition is applied to all object files.
But, I'd love to hear about the first point.

Oh I might see what you mean with your second point (about object files).
So, how would you suggest is the proper way? It is a real open question.

If you have to build object files two different ways, the only way to do it reliably is to either name them differently or put them into two different directories so they are not mixed together.  If you don't do that, then you have always remember to run make clean (or the equivalent) before you try building the "other" form, and you  have to remember which is the form that you last built to know whether to run make clean or not.
